# Is it possible to prove without Schanuel's conjecture that LambertW(1) is not an elementary number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory

1.)

Is it possible to prove without Schanuel's conjecture that LambertW(1) is not an elementary number?

-LambertW$(1)$ is the solution of the equation $x+e^x=0$.

The elementary numbers are defined in [Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165) and in [Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf).

Chow proved that Schanuel's conjecture implies that LambertW$(1)\notin\mathbb{E}$, the field of the elementary numbers.

2.)

Could Chow's proof go also with Hermite-Lindemann theorem instead of Schanuel's conjecture?
Hermite-Lindemann theorem: Let $\beta$ be a nonzero complex number. Then one at least of the two numbers $\beta$ and $e^\beta$ is transcendental.
If yes, that would mean, all corollaries of Chow's theorem does not depend on Schanuel's conjecture but are proved now.

Comment: Chow is definitely allowing some transcendental numbers as elementary. So Hermite-Lindemann or Gelfond-Schneider do not help. As  I recall, it is pretty easy to show that the number is transcendental...

Comment: What about $\cos(1)$ ? It is transcendental, but surely elementary .Also, there are algebraic numbers that do not have a closed form, apparently root of ... is not allowed.

Comment: @ Will Jagy @ Peter Let's take the Hermite-Lindemann theorem cited in my question. It is for complex numbers. It is Schanuel's conjecture proved for adjunction of only two elements.